# Is it possible to rotate the home screen in the Eclipse Android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I'm working on an application that will appear on the home screen that I've been testing on my phone in debug mode.  However, none of the five phones I have will switch the home screen into portrait mode, making it impossible to test my app in portrait mode.  I know that ctrl+F11 will rotate the emulator between portrait and landscape modes.  However, much like my physical phones the emulator, when rotated to landscape, simply displays everything sidewise at a 90 degree angle.

Is there a way that the emulator can be setup to allow a landscape home screen?  If not, how does one test an application that requires that short of buying one of the few phones that support it?

Answer (score 0):

you can press ***`Numpad 7`*** to rotate the emulator

Comment: This does the same as ctrl+F11.  It rotates the emulator, but the homescreen just appears sideways.

Comment: oops, didn't read your question carefully.
your problem is with android not with the emulator as maybe it does not support rotating homescreen to landscape mode.